# Name cannot be display

Tags: c, char, user-input, scanf

The Question : When the input is <kbd>*</kbd> and <kbd>#</kbd>, the user need to  re-enter the name. There is a maximum input limit which is 25 characters and ends the entry with <kbd>enter</kbd> key.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#define MAX 25
char welcomeMsg[]= "Please enter your name without '*' or # " ;
char errorMsg[]= "\nError, please re-type your name. ";

void main(void)
{
int j;
char input;
char name[MAX];
j=0;
puts(welcomeMsg);

do
{
    input = getche();
    if(input == '*' || input =='#' )
    {
        puts(errorMsg);
        j = 0;
        continue;
    }
    scanf("%s", name[j]);
    j++;
} while ( j < MAX && input != '\r' );

name[j] = NULL;
puts("\nYour name is");
puts(name);
}
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: You don't have to add `\0` explicitly in string literals.

Comment: `main` is wrongly declared! Should be `int main(int argc, char**argv)`. And `getche` is not defined. You should test the result of `scanf` (number of scanned items)

Comment: The program will crash when I typed a name into the program.

Comment: So you have a bug. Compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) and **use the debugger** (`gdb`); then **think** to find the bug

Comment: I don't really know how to do that and I'm using Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: You need to learn how to do that. Dive into your compiler's and debugger's documentation. Then run the program step by step in your debugger. Query (in the debugger) the value of some variables and the program state. *Think*. Improve your code. Repeat till you are satisfied. Be scared of [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Comment: @YuHao in this case, adding '\0' is necessary.

Comment: @ammoQ I meant the `\0` in the **string literal**, in [the original code](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/31129738/1).

Comment: You could use [strchr](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strchr.html) to find a character in a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified your code. Please see the snipet code below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#define MAX 25
char welcomeMsg[]= "Please enter your name without '*' or # " ;
char errorMsg[]= "\nError, please re-type your name. ";

void main(void)
{
    int j;
    char input;
    char name[MAX];
    j=0;
    puts(welcomeMsg);

    do
    {
        input = getche();
        if(input == '*' || input =='#' )
        {
            puts(errorMsg);
            j = 0;
            continue;
        }
        name[j] = input;
        j++;
    } while ( j < MAX && input != '\r' );

    name[j] = 0;
    puts("\nYour name is");
    puts(name);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, I have learned a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
scanf("%s", name[j]);
```

is wrong, write

```
 name[j] = input;
```

instead. scanf would read the whole string, given the format string,
but your program apparently needs to read character-wise.

You also need

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

in the beginning.

Oh, and

```
name[j] < 25
```

should be

```
j < MAX
```

More bugfixes:

```
char name[MAX+1]; /* one more for the terminating 0 */

name[j]=0; /* instead of NULL */
```

Comment: In order to display names that are 25 characters and below, we need to type in using the 4 arrow keys on our keyboard, as well as { } , . etc

Comment: Support for arrow keys etc. is definitely outside the scope of a simple answer here, this requires much more code.

Answer (score 0):

Your program is wrong for various reasons, like

- `scanf("%s", name[j]);`, `%s` expects a pointer to `char` array.
- `name[j] = NULL;`, NULL is a pointer type

etc.

Instead I would suggest you a cleaner algo. Check if you like it.

1. Read the user input using [`fgets()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets).
2. Search for the existence of either `*` or `#` or any other (as you want) using [`strpbrk()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strpbrk).
3. If `strpbrk()` returned NULL, that means, you are good to use the input further. The *resticted* `chars` are not there.
4. Otherwise, ask for input again.

That said, `void main(void)` is not considered a recommended signature for `main()`, you should be using `int main(void)` instead.